# Form will not send Information

Tags: html, forms, submit, mailto

So I have been sitting here racking my brain for a few hours and just cannot seem to find what I have wrong here. I am trying to get my form to send the information that the user inputs to my email. When I click send nothing happens... Anything would help! Thanks!

Here is the code I have atm:

### Email me!

```
<div class="formCenter">

    <form action="MAILTO:myemail@yahoo.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        First Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
        Email:<br>
        <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Comments:<br>
        <textarea name="commentBox" rows="6" cols="40"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">&nbsp;
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">


    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you have to send the Action to a page like Email.PHP (or ASP.net ect) which will process your POST variables.

Example:

```
<?php
$firstame = $_POST['firstName'];
?>
```

You then have to use Mail(), which will work on most servers but sometimes it won't so you can use a tool like PHPMailer which is an object orientated tool.

As you are providing the link as MAILTO, it opens up your local mail client to send an email with the POST variables listed, which is very unprofessional at best. You are better off having a link that goes to MAILTO for the time being, perhaps with a hidden value like  or something like that, so when they open the client it automatically generates an email that they can just click. With that being said, you would keep your form layout as it is, but just swap out variables so they don't appear.

The reason you didn't see anything when you clicked Send is because even though your TYPE is a submit, you sometimes need the Value and/or Name to be Submit. Some browsers and servers will treat it differently, even frameworks like Bootsrap. If you change your name and value to Submit then change one back to Send to see what works for you, you can keep it in the Send format, given that it works.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input! This helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
<?php
if($_POST["message"]) {
    mail("your@email.address", "Form to email message", $_POST["message"], "From: an@email.address");
}
?>
```

see this page http://htmldog.com/techniques/formtoemail/

Comment: I am pretty new to all this so thanks for the link that explains a lot! Going to try to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

The form itself is not able to send the email. What the code does is prompts you to select email client software such as Outlook.

Did you check whether your email client software work properly? A reboot of machine is also a mean of troubleshooting.

Comment: Decided to try the php so it is more professional, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**

```js
    function submitEmail() {
        var fname = $.trim($("#txtfname").val());
        var lname = $.trim($("#txtlname").val());
        var email = $.trim($("#txtemail").val());
        var comments = $.trim($("#txtComments").val());
        

        if (isValidEmail(email) &&  (fname.length > 1) && (lname.length > 1)) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.aspx/SubmitEmail",
                data: "{'Email':'" + $.trim($("#txtemail").val()) + "'," + "'FName':'" + $.trim($("#txtfname").val()) + "'," + "'LName':'" + $.trim($("#txtlname").val()) + "'," + "'Comments':'" + $.trim($("#txtComments").val()) + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.d != "null") {
                        var JsonObj = $.parseJSON(response.d);
                        if (JsonObj._Status == "OK") {

                           alert('Success Email :)')
                        }
                        else {
                            alert(JsonObj._Message);
                        }
                    }
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });

        }
        else {
            
            return false;
        }
    }
function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    };


 
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function SubmitEmail(ByVal Email As String, ByVal FName As String, ByVal LName As String,  ByVal Comments As String) As String
       
        Dim _serializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
        
        Dim jSonRes As String = String.Empty
        
        Dim MyString As New StringBuilder()

        MyString.Append("First Name: " & FName).Append(Environment.NewLine)
        MyString.Append("Last Name: " & LName).Append(Environment.NewLine)
        MyString.Append("Email Address: " & Email).Append(Environment.NewLine)
        MyString.Append("Comments: " & Comments).Append(Environment.NewLine)
    
        Try
                
            Dim Message As New Net.Mail.MailMessage("Do-Not-Reply@test.com", "myemail@yahoo.com")
                
            Message.CC.Add("test@test.com,test@test.com")
                
            Message.Subject = "New Request from " & FName & " " & LName
                
            Message.IsBodyHtml = False
                
            Message.Body = MyString.ToString()
                
            Dim SmtpMail As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
                
            SmtpMail.Host = "localhost"
                
            SmtpMail.Send(Message)
                
            jSonRes = _serializer.Serialize(New With {._Status = "OK", ._Message = ""})
                
        Catch ex As Exception
                
            jSonRes = _serializer.Serialize(New With {._Status = "Error", ._Message = ex.Message})
                
        End Try
        Return jSonRes
        
    End Function
```

```html
<form action="index.aspx/submitEmail" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        First Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="fname"><br>
        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lname"><br>
        Email:<br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="txtemail"><br>
        Comments:<br>
        <textarea name="commentBox" rows="6" cols="40" id="txtComments"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">&nbsp;
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">


    </form>
```

This is the correct way to send a email. You can also use a php or C# code for sending a email. I have used vb.net code(webmethod) for sending email.

Comment: I have never used vb.net with html, so I am not sure how to link it all together. I'm new to all this and still in college at the moment!